# Need to GetWebResouceUrl from within a WCF web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I need to extract a resource from a DLL. When called from a web page, I use:

```
return Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "xxx.ASPNET.Modules.Resources.16.news.png");
```

But in WCF, I obviously don't have the ClientScript property/ClientScriptManager type.

So how can I get a URL? I can only assume it cannot be done but thought I'd ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nothing stopping you doing this within your wcf service:

```
System.Web.UI.Page oPage = new System.Web.UI.Page();
string strURL = oPage.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyClass), "Stuff");
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it. And as an aside, it turns out you can't use numbers as part of the resource identifier.